Lenovo T410 - wifi driver not working
I installed ubuntu 22.04.3 to my old Lenovo ThinkPad T410 and wifi isn't working. I reinstalled OS few times... it worked on server release and when i installed this one again it hasn't been working since. what could be the issue? ethernet works fine. It's not showing as a device...
and i don't have any ethernet cable on hand.

Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos
